# Sublime Build to compile and run JavaFX code

Tags: linux, javafx, sublimetext3

I want to use a Sublime Build that compiles and runs Java Code that makes use of JavaFX.

I set up a bash command "javafx "file"" that will execute the command lines javac ... and java ... shown in the first bit of code.
The javafx command works perfectly fine, the $PATH_TO_FX exists, no trouble there.

Then I try to include this javafx bash command in Sublime with the second bit of code. The Sublime console then proceeds to show an Error for every import statement that tries to import some javafx class.

It appears as if Sublime was using another type of console that does not know the whereabouts of $PATH_TO_FX ... Could that be?

## working bash command

`javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls $1 && java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls $1`

## not working sublime build

`{
    "shell_cmd": "javafx $file",
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java",
}`

Comment: The working bash command and the command that's not working are not the same thing; are you saying that the bash command is in a shell script called `javafx`? Also, what platform are you running on?

Comment: The bash command (javac ... + java ...) are saved in a bash script named javafx. Thus the javafx command should invoke precisely those two subcommands. I am running on Linux, sorry to not having mentioned that.

Comment: Best guess would be that there is an environment variable that Sublime is not seeing that exists in the terminal when you run it there. Sublime should have the same environment as the terminal unless you run something there that sets up variables that the script isn't running, or unless you modified your environment without restarting Sublime and/or your window manager.